# R cannot open: lost cufft64_80.dll

Tags: r, dll, cuda

I have tried to install mxnet GPU package, but failed. Thus, I stepped to use CPU instead. However, I met this problem, there is an error opening R and Rstudio.

I have searched to find that cufft64_80.dll is in CUDA library, but I can't install NVIDIA CUDA 8.0 in windows neither.

How can I deal with that? Is there some places I can download this dll?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I delete Visual Studio 2013 and download Visual Studio 2015, I manage to install NVIDIA CUDA 8.0. Thus, there is no error anymore.
Don't forget to turn all the anti-virus software.

PS: I am curious about the person who vote -1 of my question. Is there anything wrong with it? 
I am new to stack overflow, and I really cherish about my reputation. Why do you vote -1? Can you tell me the reason so that I can amend it? Thank you.